# How do I add JavaScript into FPDF?

Tags: javascript, php, fpdf

I'm using [FDPF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and I want to add a JavaScript chart that I created with D3 into the pdf. I was able to visualize the chart into an HTML webpage with the following code. I'm simply appending the chart into the div id "chart."

```
<!-- Circular Bar Chart start -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 large-centered columns chart-container">
        <h2>Circular Bar Chart</h2>
        <div id="chart" class="text-center"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Usually, when you add an image into a PDF with FDPF you use the following code. I'm simply appending the chart to the div id "chart"

```
// Insert image
$pdf->Image('images/graphic_cropped.jpg',15,3,130);
```

How can I insert the chart that I generated with D3 into my PDF with FPDF?

Comment: FPDF can only handle Adobe Acrobat JS, it can't be used to parse other JS.

Answer (score 0):

Since FDPF is a server-side (php) library and you are generating the image on the client, you need to do something like this:

- Generate the chart
- Save chart to SVG (see, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079566/d3-js-download-graph-as-svg-image))
- Encode the image into base64 string (see, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293795/server-side-d3-encoding-svg-as-a-base64-image))
- Post the image to your php server (I think you can find how to POST data from javascript to php and you already have your image as a string)
- On php side - [decode the base64](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) string back to binary image
- Now use FDPF to insert the image into PDF

You may also consider [generating PDF on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript).